# Sorting an array of objects by values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to sort an array of objects by its values and I use this code to do this:

`function compare(a,b){return dict[a]-dict[b]}
 Object.keys(dict).sort(compare)`

it works if each value is different, but if two objects have the same value, it leaves them in the order they appear in the array but I want them to be sorted alphabetically. I couldn't figure out a way to do that.

`dict = {a:1, d:4, c:2, b:4, e:5, f:3}` should be :

```
{a:1, c:2, f:3, b:4, d:4, e:5 }
```

but I'm getting this:

```
{a:1, c:2, f:3, d:4, b:4, e:5 }
```

Comment: That's not even an array

Comment: `Object.keys()` returns an array, and you're sorting that array. The result will be an array, not an object.

Comment: so if the difference is zero, sort by the keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the compareFunction to use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```
dict[a] - dict[b] || a.localeCompare(b)
```

If `dict[a] - dict[b]` returns 0, it checks the next condition and sorts the keys alphabetically

Here's a snippet:

```js
const dict = {a:1, d:4, c:2, b:4, e:5, f:3}

function compare(a, b) {
  return dict[a] - dict[b] || a.localeCompare(b)
}

const sorted = Object.keys(dict)
                      .sort(compare)
                      .reduce((acc, k) => (acc[k] = dict[k], acc), {})

console.log( sorted )
```

Answer (score 1):

So compare the keys if the diff is equal to zero

```js
function compare(a, b) {
  var diff = dict[a] - dict[b]
  return diff === 0 ? a.localeCompare(b) : diff
}

const dict = {
  a: 1,
  d: 4,
  c: 2,
  b: 4,
  e: 5,
  f: 3
}

const result = Object.keys(dict).sort(compare).reduce((o, x) => ({
  ...o,
  [x]: dict[x],
}), {})

console.log(result)
```